# d3.js Tree Layout - Cross Links

Tags: graph, d3.js, tree, visualization, force-layout

I created an interactive force-directed tree of related objects with d3. The nodes and links are created using the d3 tree layout.

The data structure is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "node name",
  "id": 1,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "child node name",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "child node name",
      "id": 3
    },
    ...
  ]
},
...
```

The nodes/links are created the following way:

```
var nodes = flatten(rootNode);
var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
```

To enable bidirectional traversal of the tree, I recursively walk down the tree from every newly created node and add parent references to all nodes.

It is possible to extend the tree by clicking on a leaf node. Then data is loaded via AJAX and the tree is updated.

The problem with this is that objects with the same ID/Name might occur multiple times in the tree. Is there a way to cleanly merge all duplicate nodes (which would convert the tree into a graph due to cross links) from the JavaScript code?

**Edit:** Maybe the only way to do this would be to walk down the entire tree and re-link all links that point to the duplicate... Although I think that this could slow the script down considerably...

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle for better visualization?

Comment: @manu: It's hard to replicate due to the dynamic AJAX calls... I don't need actual code as an answer, it's more of a conceptual question :)

Comment: just for understanding: has each node its unique id? after that, each node can be placed below multiple parents?

Comment: @manu each node should have a unique id. the problem is that two nodes with the same id (which means they're the same database object) can be in the tree after loading more data, so they should be merged, including all links.

Answer (score 0):

i see... what about keeping an addtional list with all available tree nodes? this way you would not have to traverse the hierarchy recursivly.

Comment: The problem isn't the traversal (I can get a flat list of all nodes with the `flatten()` function), it's how to detect duplicates and to link them together while (if possible) keeping the basic tree layout. I assumed there could be a clean d3 way to do this.